# MySQL installation error: libmariadbclient-dev conflicts with libmysqlclient-dev

Tags: 17.10, mysql

I am trying the install mysql-server_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb-bundle in Ubuntu 17.10 laptop. I am having the following error,

```
dpkg: regarding libmysqlclient-dev_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb containing libmysqlclient-dev:
 libmariadbclient-dev conflicts with libmysqlclient-dev
  libmysqlclient-dev (version 5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libmysqlclient-dev_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing libmysqlclient-dev
```

The full terminal output is this,

```
/Downloads$ cd mysql-server_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb-bundle/
user@laptop:~/Downloads/mysql-server_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb-bundle$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
(Reading database ... 384833 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libmysqlclient20_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) over (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
dpkg: regarding libmysqlclient-dev_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb containing libmysqlclient-dev:
 libmariadbclient-dev conflicts with libmysqlclient-dev
  libmysqlclient-dev (version 5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libmysqlclient-dev_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing libmysqlclient-dev
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqld-dev.
Preparing to unpack libmysqld-dev_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqld-dev (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Replaced by files in installed package libmariadbd-dev:amd64 (10.1.30-0ubuntu0.17.10.1) ...
Preparing to unpack mysql-client_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) over (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
dpkg: warning: downgrading mysql-common from 5.8+1.0.2ubuntu1 to 5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10
Preparing to unpack mysql-common_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) over (5.8+1.0.2ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-client_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-client (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) over (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-server_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb ...
.
Unpacking mysql-community-server (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) over (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-source_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-source (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) over (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-test.
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-test_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-test (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Preparing to unpack mysql-server_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) over (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-testsuite.
Preparing to unpack mysql-testsuite_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-testsuite (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmysqld-dev:
 libmysqld-dev depends on libmysqlclient-dev (= 5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10); however:
  Package libmysqlclient-dev is not installed.
 libmariadbd18:amd64 (10.1.30-0ubuntu0.17.10.1) breaks libmysqld-dev and is installed.
 libmariadbd-dev:amd64 (10.1.30-0ubuntu0.17.10.1) breaks libmysqld-dev and is installed.

dpkg: error processing package libmysqld-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback ...
Setting up mysql-community-client (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Setting up mysql-community-source (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-community-test:
 mysql-community-test depends on libmysqlclient-dev; however:
  Package libmysqlclient-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-test (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-testsuite:
 mysql-testsuite depends on mysql-community-test (= 5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10); however:
  Package mysql-community-test is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-testsuite (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Setting up mysql-client (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Setting up mysql-server (5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (234-2ubuntu12.3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmysqlclient-dev_5.7.21-1ubuntu17.10_amd64.deb
 libmysqld-dev
 mysql-community-test
 mysql-testsuite
```

Anyone here to suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried run `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: Yes. Here is the result https://gist.github.com/haseebmahmud/e42715ed0e41b219a61c9947527556aa

Comment: you can remove `libmariadbclient-dev` which causing the conflict , but before that please check the packages which depend on it, with `sudo apt-cache rdepends libmariadbclient-dev`